# Print only git branch prefix

Tags: git, git-branch

I would like to print only the branch name prefixes of a git repo. For example, if a repo had the following branches,

```bash
  bug/nasty-problem
  feature/neat-thing
  feature/awesome-thing
  main
```

is there a way to print only `bug`, `feature`, and `main`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work in your case if you're using terminal etc.

```
git branch --list | awk -F'/' '{print $1}' | sort -u
```

1. git branch --list: Lists all branches in the repository
2. awk -F'/' '{print $1}': Uses awk to set the field separator to '/' and prints the first field AKA branch name prefix.
3. sort -u: Sorts the output and removes duplicates (-u stands for unique)

Comment: This works! I was hoping for a built in git argument, but I couldn't find anything in the docs